# Load CPU at a specific % with stress-ng

Tags: cpu, compute-module-3

I'm trying to achieve a 50% CPU load on my Pi to run thermal tests on it since that's what I expect the CPU usage to be with the real application. So far I've been playing around with `stress-ng` and found that it has an option for setting the desired CPU load (default setting is 100%): `stress-ng -c 4 --cpu-load 50`. But it doesn't look like it works - CPU usage just jumps between 100% and 0%. Has anyone had any experience with a similar problem? Is there a better tool out there to accomplish this?

Comment: It wasn't common in my search. Check it, change the loop by the current percentage: https://askubuntu.com/a/1027556/859552